# EditText input element hide in the android alert dialog when soft key pad visible

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-keypad

In my new app I want to give a pop to add password to login. It's having a EditText Input,Title and Message.
Edit text gave as,
final EditText input = new EditText(view.getContext());

Issue is when soft keypad pops out edittext becomes invisible.Other feilds remains as it is.
Sometimes in the 1st approach it doesn't happen.Currently this issue came with OS 10. OS 11 worked finely. Hope a solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MYrd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Jzw.png)

Also I refered previous questions and add changes to manifest files with "windowSoftInputMode".Didn't worked.